# Find all nonzero values of $k$ such that the vectors $(-11; k; 2)$ and $(k; k^2; k)$ are orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find all nonzero values of $k$ such that the vectors $(-11; k; 2)$ and $(k; k^2; k)$ are orthogonal.

Can someone help me with this thanks?

Comment: Is $k2=2 k$....?

Comment: Its k^2 sorry..

Comment: Vectors are orthogonal iff their dot product is zero. Take the dot product and solve for k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The *dot* product of the two vectors is $$-11.k+k.k^2+2.k=k(k^2-9).$$ The two vectors will be orthogonal when this *dot* product is zero. So, when this (i.e., for what values of $k\ne0$, by your requirement) *dot* product vanishes?